# How to not lose "this" when using Array.find

Tags: javascript, class, this

I am using Array.find in the following context

```
module.exports = new class {
   status = { COMMAND_SUCCESS: 1 }

   commands = [{
        name: "history",
        method: this.History
   }];

   commandsNames = ["history"];

   async Execute(command)
   {
        var commandParts = command.toLowerCase().split(" ");
        var commandFound = this.commands.find((command) => { return command.name === commandParts[0] });
        // Removed if commandFound for clarity
        return commandFound["method"]();
   }

   async History()
   {
      // Removed first lines for clarity
      return this.status.COMMAND_SUCCESS; 
      // Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'COMMAND_SUCCESS')
   }
}
```

I am tryingh to keep the THIS scope inside my method so i can access the status object.
How can i keep the this of my class inside the History method ?
My first try was to update my commandFound variable, the original version was

```
.find(command => command.name === commandParts[0]);
```

Comment: `method: this.History` -> `method: () => this.History()`

Comment: @VLAZ it worked, but I have a post limit, can you make a full answer so i can put it as the correct response ? Thanks btw

Comment: `commandFound["method"].call(this)`